# Why isn't my first click being registered in state in my React container?

Tags: reactjs, onclick, event-handling, state

I'm working on a matching game and have written a handleClick function that should increment a state value called guessCount so I can keep track of each time a player guesses. I also want to save the IDs of each item clicked as guessOne and guessTwo in state. For some reason the first click won't trigger my setState guessCount increment code nor capture the clicked item's IDs. Each click after does work correctly, except that it's one click behind the user's actual clicks.

```
state = {
  guessCount: 0,
  guessOne: null,
  guessTwo: null
}

handleClick = (e) => {
  this.setState({ guessCount: this.state.guessCount + 1 });

  if(this.state.guessCount === 1) {
    this.setState({ guessOne: e.currentTarget.dataset.id });
    this.setState({ guessCount: this.state.guessCount + 1 });
  }
  if(this.state.guessCount === 2) {
    this.setState({ guessTwo: e.currentTarget.dataset.id });
    this.setState({ guessCount: 0 });
  }
}
```

Expected results: On first click, the guessCount would increment from 0 to 1 and the clicked item's ID would be set in state to guessOne. On second click the guessCount would increment from 1 to 2, the clicked item's ID would be set in state to guessTwo, then the guessCount would be reset to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since react state updates are asynchronous,they are not updated immediately.
There is no guarantee that after you call

```
this.setState({ guessCount: this.state.guessCount + 1 });
```

"guessCount" will set to 1 immediately.Hence while it reaches the condition "guessCount" may remain zero.

React Docs : https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous

You could either put your conditional checks inside a function and pass that function as a callback which will get called once state is updated.

```
handleClick = (e) => {
    this.setState({ guessCount: this.state.guessCount + 1 },()=>{
         countUpdaterFunction();
    });
}
```

Comment: This solved it for me! I put my conditionals in a separate function and that worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`setState` is **asynchronous**, you should use an [updater](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) function to get the state value at the time the change is being applied.

```
handleClick = (e) => {
   this.setState(state => ({ guessCount: state.guessCount + 1 }));

   if (this.state.guessCount === 1) {
     this.setState({ guessOne: e.currentTarget.dataset.id });
     this.setState(state => ({ guessCount: state.guessCount + 1 }));
   }

   if(this.state.guessCount === 2) {
      this.setState({ guessTwo: e.currentTarget.dataset.id });
      this.setState({ guessCount: 0 });
   }
}
```

By the way I think you can have some problem with your code, imagine the function `handleClick` is called twice without giving the time to `setState` to update the component state, I would prefer the following solution where I store the key `guessOne` or `guessTwo` in the component state

```
constructor() {
   this.state = {
      guessKey: 'guessOne'
   };
}

handleClick = (e) => {
   this.setState(state => ({
      [state.guessKey]: e.currentTarget.dataset.id,
      guessKey: state.guessKey === 'guessOne' ? 'guessTwo' : 'guessOne'
   }));
}
```

Comment: Oh duh, that makes sense. I'm wondering then if I should move the conditionals into a componentDidUpdate function so I'm not calling setState twice in the same onClick function?

Comment: I updated my solution to show you a different solution